# Low FPS in Swing Application

Tags: java, swing

Hello I'm building a relatively small 2D Game based off of the Original Snake Using Java and Swing GUI's. I am getting incredibly low FPS counts in the range of ~7 to ~10 FPS even though my application is very small at the moment. All that is displayed to the screen is 4 10x10 PNG's so this is slightly worrying considering what I was hoping to implement.

The code for my main class is given below, and the method I am using to display the FPS is given below that.

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private final int BOARD_WIDTH = 300;
    private final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 300;
    private final int SEGMENT_SIZE = 10;
    private final int MAX_PARTS = (BOARD_WIDTH / SEGMENT_SIZE) * (BOARD_HEIGHT * SEGMENT_SIZE);
    private final int DELAY = 140;
    private final int RAND_POS = 29;

    private final int x[] = new int[MAX_PARTS];
    private final int y[] = new int[MAX_PARTS];

    private int bodyLen;
    private int appleX;
    private int appleY;

    private boolean rightDirection = true;
    private boolean leftDirection = false;
    private boolean upDirection = false;
    private boolean downDirection = false;
    private boolean inGame = true;

    private Timer timer;
    private Image body;
    private Image head;
    private Image apple;

    private FPSCounter fpscount;

    public Board() {
        initBoard();
    }

    private void initBoard() {
        fpscount = new FPSCounter();
        fpscount.start();
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setFocusable(true);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT));
        loadImages();
        initGame();
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        ImageIcon app = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/Apple.png");
        apple = app.getImage();

        ImageIcon bod = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/Body.png");
        body = bod.getImage();
    }

    private void initGame() {
        bodyLen = 3;
        for(int i = 0; i < bodyLen; i++) {
            x[i] = 50 - i * 10;
            y[i] = 50;
        }

        getApple();

        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
        fpscount.frame(); //added line (step 4).
        g.drawString("" + fpscount.get(), 5, 22); //added line (step 5).
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        if (inGame) {
            g.drawImage(apple, appleX, appleY, this);

            for(int i = 0; i < bodyLen; i++) {
                g.drawImage(body, x[i], y[i], this);
            }

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        }
    }

    private void getApple() {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        appleX = r * SEGMENT_SIZE;

        r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        appleY = r * SEGMENT_SIZE;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(inGame) {
            move();
        }
        repaint();
    }
    private void move() {
        for(int i = bodyLen; i > 0; i--) {
            x[i] = x[i - 1];
            y[i] = y[i - 1];
        }

        if(leftDirection) {
            x[0] -= SEGMENT_SIZE;
        }
        if(rightDirection) {
            x[0] += SEGMENT_SIZE;
        }
        if(upDirection) {
            y[0] -= SEGMENT_SIZE;
        }
        if(downDirection) {
            y[0] += SEGMENT_SIZE;
        }
    }



    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (!leftDirection)) {
                rightDirection = true;
                upDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;
                leftDirection = false;
            }
            if((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!rightDirection)) {
                leftDirection = true;
                upDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;
                rightDirection = false;
            }
            if((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (!downDirection)) {
                upDirection = true;
                rightDirection = false;
                leftDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;
            }
            if((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (!upDirection)) {
                downDirection = true;
                leftDirection = false;
                rightDirection = false;
                upDirection = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FPS Counter Class

```
        private final Timer resetTimer;
        private int current, last;

        public FPSCounter() {
            resetTimer = new Timer(1000, this);
        }

        public synchronized void start() {
            resetTimer.start();
            current = 0;
            last = -1;
        }

        public synchronized void stop() {
            resetTimer.stop();
            current = -1;
        }

        public synchronized void frame() {
            current++;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            last = current;
            current = 0;
        }

        public synchronized int get() {
            return last;
        }
    }
```

Maybe it's just my FPS Counter class that is off but any information you could give that might be able to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
private final int DELAY = 140;
```

Your delay is 140.

So your frames per second will be 1000 / 140 = 7.14.

Typically people aim for a frame rate of 60. So you should use a delay of 1000 / 60 = 16.